# Declaring SDL_Rect data member crashes on launch, can't find why

Tags: c++, crash, sdl

When I declare the following as a private data member of my main class "App", my program crashes on launch as if it was accessing invalid data/memory (EDIT: it doesn't crash if it is a public data member):

```
//Display position and dimensions of the entire app
SDL_Rect DisplayRect;
```

If I remove this, program launches fine, but I really don't understand why. I verified the following things:

- SDL library was initialized correctly
- The "SDL_Rect" header is included
- The compiler throws no warning or error

It doesn't make any sense, and I have private SDL_Rect data members in other classes and they don't cause any problem. I think it's something about initialization but I don't get why I should have to do anything special in this case. Here are all my data members and my initialization list for my App class:

```
/* Private data members */
private:

//Whether or not the app loop is running
bool running;

//The starting time of the program, starting when the App object is created
clock_t start_time;

//Variable holding count of loops executed after the App object entered its main loop - use the defined public method
//to increase the count at the proper location inside the App object's main loop
long long int loop_count;

//SDL Window pointer to hold the main application window
SDL_Window* MainWindow;

//Event Manager object to check and manage main application events
EventManager MainEvents;

//SDL renderer pointer to perform rendering operations
SDL_Renderer* MainRenderer;

//App dependencies structure to be passed to lower level objects for dependency injection
AppDependencies MainDependencies;

//Room object holding data for the current room into which the App is running - initialize with default values
Room CurrentRoom;

//Display position and dimensions of the entire app
SDL_Rect DisplayRect;


/* Public methods */
public:

//Constructor - Initialization list
App() :

    MainDependencies(this->MainWindow, &this->MainEvents, this->MainRenderer),
    CurrentRoom(&this->MainDependencies, RoomId::SPLASH_SCREEN, 1024, 768, 1024, 768)

    {
        //Set data member telling that the app is running
        this->running = true;

        //Get the starting time of the App object
        this->start_time = clock();

        //Set loop count to 0
        this->loop_count = 0;

        //Set MainWindow pointer to null
        MainWindow = nullptr;

        //Set MainRenderer pointer to null
        MainRenderer = nullptr;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was that I had to declare my SDL_Rect before the two objects initialized in the initializer list.

I didn't know that declaration ordered mattered like this, hope it can help people in the future!

Comment: I know this is a super old post but if there's any additional information on this, that would be great. I'm running into the same problem and changing the order of initialization doesn't seem to fix the issue. Thanks!